# Using google-maps logo without google-maps tiles

Tags: google-maps

We are using Google Maps in our application. We are not showing Google Map tiles instead of this we are showing tiles from other sources (e.g. Open Street Map) by tile overlays. So as a result we are showing maps from other source based on Google Maps with Google Maps logo in the left bottom corner. Is it allowed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terms of use (legal issues) not coding.

Comment: Where should I find answer on this issue than?

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Google Maps API you have to follow Terms of Service of Google Maps APIs. The Terms of Service is pretty straight forward regarding links and logos. Have a look at paragraph 10.5 (g), it reads:

> **No removing, obscuring, or altering terms of service, links, or proprietary rights notices.** You will not:
>
> - remove, obscure, or alter any Google terms of service or any links to or notices of those terms, or any copyright, trademark, or other proprietary rights notices; or
> - falsify or delete any author attributions, legal notices, or other labels of the origin or source of material.

So you shouldn't hide Google logo and links when you use tile overlays from OSM.

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions

I hope this addresses your doubt.